# Java - Thread calls doMain() when no run() exists?

Tags: java, multithreading

I've recently started working on a Java Project that was done many years ago and I'm trying to understand the code as much as I can (considering I'm somewhat of a beginner trying to evolve).

Here's my doubt:
I have two classes, let's say it's ClassA and ClassB that don't extend one another.
In ClassA there's a main method that runs the following code:

```
Thread object = new Thread(ClassB);
object.start();
```

From my understanding of threads, this should call a run() method on ClassB.
However the most important method on ClassB is a doMain() method and there is no run().

How do I know if doMain() is actually the method being called?

Thanks for the help :)

P.S. This is an example code, the real code is 1000x more complex and maybe there are nuances that I'm not getting, but any clues on what to do would be great.

Comment: add some debugging code to it.

Comment: If "there is no run()" in ClassB, then the class from the object ClassB is not implementing Runnable, so the constructor call new Thread(ClassB) should not compile. see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread(java.lang.Runnable)

Comment: I doubt you can compile "new Thread(ClassB);". You need to make an instance of ClassB, e.g. new ClassB(). If your ClassB does not implements Runnable then the code would not compile either. Last, the ClassB cannot implement Runnable without having run() method. So either your code does not compile or you do have run method, perhaps in parent class as others suggested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is two constructors for Thread you must be using here

```
Thread object = new Thread(classB);
```

Either classB is a `String` or `Runnable`. There is no other options which will compile.  Assuming it is not a `String`, and it is a Runnable it must have a `run()` method or it won't compile (or if its an abstract class you can't create an instance)

In short, you have a `run()` method.

> This is an example code, the real code is 1000x more complex and maybe there are nuances that I'm not getting, but any clues on what to do would be great.

The simplest way to prove this is to check the call hierarchy of `doMain()` in your IDE or add a breakpoint on this line and run your code in your debugger.

Comment: thanks when checking the call hierarchy I can see that the run() is called on a parent class.

Answer (score 1):

The method Thread.start always calls the **run** method, it's stated explicitly in the documentation: [Thread#start()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start()).

Perhaps that your class with the doMain method **inherits** some other class, where the doMain method is **abstract** and the run method, defined in the same parent class, calls it?

Comment: That's probably it. ClassB isn't abstract, but it extends a certain ClassC that contains a run() method. And classC calls the doMain().